# using hardware backbutton as exit app in home page in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs

so I have an app that have a log in  with and register page, but I dont want have a log out, because this is a chatting app. this code is in my app.js in as angularjs:

```
//login
    $scope.islogin = false;
    $scope.login = {};
    $scope.loginFn = function(){
        socket.emit('login',$scope.login,function(callback){
            if(!callback['error']){
                $scope.islogin = true;
                localStorageService.add('user',callback);
                $location.path('/home');
                $scope.datauser =localStorageService.get('user');
                $scope.$apply();
            }else{
                alert(callback['error']);
            }
        });
    };

//cek localstorage
    ($scope.cekLocalStorage = function(){
        if(!$scope.datauser){
            $location.path('/');
            localStorageService.remove('user');
        }
    })();
```

my question is I wanna make the hardware back button as an exit app when in the home page using  `navigator.app.exitApp();`, I have several pages in this application, but when other page backbutton will just be `navigator.app.backHistory()`. I have look up from other question, what I get is use `javascript`:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady(){
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e){
       if($.mobile.activePage.is('#homepage')){
           e.preventDefault();
           navigator.app.exitApp();
       }
       else {
           navigator.app.backHistory()
       }
    }, false);
}
```

and I got use `Ionic` framework too:

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function() {
//var path = $location.path()
  if ($location.path() === "/home" || $location.path() === "home") {
    navigator.app.exitApp();
  }
  else {
    $ionicHistory.goBack();
    //navigator.app.goBack();
  }
}, 100);
```

I want to write it in Angularjs because I dont both of them, how do I convert it? thanks

Comment: I feel **Vanilla JS** logic should be fine to use with **angular js**, it will not create any issues since its **vanilla JS** and not any other framework like **jquery**, in which case i would have said not to use that but vanilla JS is ok to use. in fact **angular JS** is a JS framework, i hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: @dreamweiver can you give a preferences? or example?

Comment: My preference would be to go with the  Javascript code , which you have posted in your question.